# Upgrade Python in Jenkins Docker

Tags: python, docker, jenkins

I currently have a docker image with Jenkins and Python.

I did something like

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python python-pip python3-pip && \
    ... (and more stuff)
... (I also install gcloud sdk)
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN /usr/bin/env python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && /usr/bin/env python3 -m pip install pipenv==2018.10.13
RUN /usr/bin/env python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && /usr/bin/env python -m pip install pipenv==2018.10.13
RUN chown jenkins /opt/app -R
USER jenkins
```

But this installs python 3.5.3 ( https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python3 )

I'd need python 3.7 (as well as python 2.7.15).

So, I'm trying my way with multiple `FROM` as explained [here](https://blog.alexellis.io/mutli-stage-docker-builds/) and [there](https://gist.github.com/praveenweb/9cabe480c1811b85337de988e43b8633). But to no avail.

```
FROM python:2.7.15-stretch as py2
FROM python:3.7.2-stretch as py3
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts as jenkins
```

I'm pretty sure it's not too complicated... once you've played with it once...

So, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It works! I did like this:

```
FROM python:3.7.2-stretch as py3

FROM python:2.7.15-stretch as py2

FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root
COPY --from=py2 /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib
COPY --from=py2 /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin
COPY --from=py2 /usr/local/include /usr/local/include
COPY --from=py2 /usr/local/man /usr/local/man
COPY --from=py2 /usr/local/share /usr/local/share

COPY --from=py3 /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib
COPY --from=py3 /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin
COPY --from=py3 /usr/local/include /usr/local/include
COPY --from=py3 /usr/local/man /usr/local/man
COPY --from=py3 /usr/local/share /usr/local/share

RUN apt-get update && \
    ...
```

Comment: I am not sure what is being done here. Is Python3.7 really installed ?

Comment: This does NOT work:  python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

**TL&DR:** This is the best way to get the latest python on the Jenkins provided docker-image.

**Description**

Create a DockerFile with the following content:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine
USER root
RUN apk add python3 && \
     python3 -m ensurepip && \
     pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools && \
     if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
     if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi && \
     rm -r /root/.cache
RUN apk add pkgconf
RUN apk add build-base
RUN apk add python3-dev
RUN apk add postgresql-dev
RUN apk add postgresql-client
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wget to download and install python version that you want.

For example, installing python3.8.12 on jenkins:lts-jdk11

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    # Tools
    sudo net-tools wget vim nfs-common arping curl \
    # Required libs 
    build-essential libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev \
    libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev libz-dev && \
    # Install python
    mkdir install_py && cd install_py && \
    sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.12/Python-3.8.12.tgz && \
    sudo tar xzf Python-3.8.12.tgz && \
    cd Python-3.8.12 && \
    sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations && \
    sudo make altinstall && \
    cd ../.. && rm -r install_py && \
    # Set default python path to use python
    sudo ln -snf /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python && \
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip

...
```